# Python function that takes lists and elements and makes one list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

Hopefully an example could illustrate this better. I am creating a function that will take either a list of names, various lists of names, just a name or multiple names (not in a list) and make one list of them all (without importing... non-native libraries? I am ignorant here but I mean I want to use only what's already available in python).

```
def make_one_list(entry1, entry2, entry3 ...):
   #regardless of what is entered (well.. it has to be list or element)
   #extract elements from list and combine with single elements and...
   return one_big_list_of_all_elements

>>>make_one_list(['John','Mark'],'Mike',['Kate','Ally'],'Shawn','Marina'...)
['John','Mark','Mike','Kate','Ally','Shawn','Marina',...]
```

My pseudo-code is not set in stone, obviously. I think, eventually, some input checking might be in order but not very pythonic in nature to do that. I am simply doing this as a personal communication function for my office.

THANKS!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the `chain` answer but a bit more straightforward at a glance

```
def make_one_list(*args):
    one_list = []
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, str):
            one_list.append(arg)
        else:
            one_list.extend(arg)
    return one_list

ret = make_one_list(['John','Mark'],'Mike',['Kate','Ally'],'Shawn','Marina')
print(ret)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a good use of `*args` in python.
Just traverse through the list of arguements and check whether the arguement is a list or not(by checking its type). If it is, just append that arguement to the `one_big_list_of_all_elements`.
Pretty simple!

Comment: same thought. I will give this a go.

Comment: I am just scared of dislikes that I often get on this website. This is my first answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`chain(iter1, iter2, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), it is a native library. Though you need to handle the strings that are not in lists.

```
from itertools import chain

data = ['John','Mark'],'Mike',['Kate','Ally'],'Shawn','Marina'
r = chain(*[x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in data])
print(list(r))
```

Output:

```
['John', 'Mark', 'Mike', 'Kate', 'Ally', 'Shawn', 'Marina']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def flatten(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        tmp = []
        for i in x:
            tmp.extend(flatten(i))
        return tmp
    else:
        return [x]
```

Test:

```
print(repr(flatten([[1, 2, 3], 4, [5], [6, [7, 8], 9]])))
print(repr(flatten(1)))
print(repr(flatten([2])))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1]
[2]
```

Fast, clean, works for any type of elements and any depth of nested lists.
Note usage of "extend" which avoids creating excessive intermediate results. This makes the function efficient even for large lists.

Comment: Pardon, this might be a stupid question - is this function not recursive? Calling flatten inside of flatten?

Comment: Of course it's recursive - it works for arbitrary depth of nested lists.

Comment: `make_one_list = lambda *x: sum([i if isinstance(i,list) else [i] for i in x ],[]);make_one_list(['John','Mark'],'Mike',['Kate','Ally'],'Shawn','Marina')`

Comment: @onyambu thats an elegant one-liner! Wow.

Answer (score 1):

```
final_list = []
def make_one_list(arg_list):
  for arg in arg_list:
    if isinstance(arg, list):
        for item in arg:
            final_list.append(item)
    else:
        final_list.append(arg)
  return final_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a = []
b = []



def myFun(*argv):  

    for arg in argv:
        a.append(arg)
    myList = str(a).replace('[','').replace(']','')
    b = [myList]
    print(b)


myFun('Hello', 'Welcome', 'to', 'Geeks',['ff','tt'])
```

OUTPUT >> ["'Hello', 'Welcome', 'to', 'Geeks', 'ff', 'tt'"]

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

We can do what you asked for by connecting all lists with **(+)**

```
def make_one_list(*args):
   result = []
   for i in args:
       if isinstance(i, list):
           result.append(list(i))
       else:
           result.append(i)
   return result

result = make_one_list(['John','Mark'], ['Kate','Ally'], ['Shawn','Marina'], 'Mike')
print(result)
```

Comment: Except there are a variable number of args, some are lists some are strings.

Comment: OP wants any number of args and any order of string and list-of-string combinations. We can't assume exactly 4 args or that the first three are lists.

Comment: @nakE It's still not right! With your approach, you can pass only 4 arguments. But OP wants to pass a variable number of arguments.

Comment: @Pavitra is it fine now ?

Comment: @tdelaney Is it fine now ?

Comment: Pretty close, except `result.append(list(i))` - `i` is already a list and all of its elements need to be added. `result.extend(i)` would do nicely.

Comment: @tdelaney Oh you right! my fault. thank you, lol I have checked if it is a list and then converting it to a list. haha